# Android Global Alert

Tags: android, dialog, alert

Lets say I have activity A B and C in my application. I make an alert dialog in activity A. After activity A finishes its long running task I want it to show the alert dialog even if the user is in activity B or C. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: "After activity A finishes its long running task".. here the Activity B/C will be started by A all the while dialog is displayed to the user i.e. you want continuous dialog display?

Comment: create an activity that has the theme of a dialog so while it looks like a dialog like you want all you have to do is start it like you would launch a normal activity and it will show up over whatever screen is up

Comment: suppose I am in activity A and start the task (downloading a file from internet)! then i navigate to activity B or C and after activity A finishes its task (the downloading) the dialog should appear stating that the download has been finished. Currently the dialog appears if i am in activity A only!